# Gutenberg custom blocks php render issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm creating some custom dynamic blocks for WordPress Gutenberg editor (following this [link](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks) ).

I use the PHP render for these blocks, meaning I have this code on save:

```
save: function( props ) {
    // Rendering in PHP
      return;

},
```

The render function is called via this callback:

```
register_block_type( 'my-plugin/latest-post', array(
    'render_callback' => 'my_plugin_render_block_latest_post',
) );
```

I'm not gonna post the function code since is irrelevant in this case. (I do
a WP_Query and display some custom post data and return a html code),

My problem is that WP Gutenberg takes the output from the function and adds 
`<p> and <br>` tags (classic wpautop behaviour).

My question is: How can I disable that only for custom blocks? I could use this:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

but I don't want to alter the default behaviour.

Some additional findings. The php function use for block rendering use get_the_excerpt(). Once this function is used (and i assume is happening for get_the_content() ) the wpautop filter is applied and the html markup of the block gets messed up.

I don't know if this is a bug or the expected behavior but is there any simple solution to this that does not involve removing the filter ? ( For ex on themeforest removing this filter is not allowed.)

Comment: Does this happens only for your custom block? Is wpautop used implicitly inside the callback?

Comment: Just edited: i find out that this is happening when you are using get_the_excerpt on the php rendering function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have by default:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_blocks', 9 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
...
```

I skimmed through the `do_blocks()` ([src](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0/src/wp-includes/blocks.php#L239)) and if I understand correctly it removes the `wpautop` filtering if the content contains any blocks, but restores the filter for any subsequent `the_content()` usage.

I wonder if your render block callback contains any such subsequent usage, as you mentioned a `WP_Query` loop.

One could e.g. try:

```
$block_content = '';

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); // Remove the filter on the content.
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' ); // Remove the filter on the excerpt.

... code in callback ...

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );    // Restore the filter on the content.
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );    // Restore the filter on the excerpt.

return $block_content;
```

within your `my_plugin_render_block_latest_post()` callback code.

Comment: I just edited the question : this is happening because i'm using get_the_excerpt()

Comment: @Crerem By default the excerpt is also filtered through `wpautop()`, I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, but when you are using it in shortcodes you are not getting this behavior. So i expect the same thing here. The remove filter solution works , makes total sense,  but is not allowed to be used on WordPress repository or themeforrest. That's why i'm trying to find an alternative solution. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, but here we're **restoring** the temporary removed filters before returning the content so that shouldn't affect other calls afterwards. Do you have a link where it's explained why this is not allowed there, that would be informative, thanks. Can you also share the shortcode example? @Crerem Another approach would be to fetch the raw field, e.g. via `get_post_field( 'post_excerpt' );`

Comment: @Crerem There are 150 matches (133 plugins) in the WordPress plugins directory that remove the `wpautop` filter from the excerpt (and most likely add it back again as we do here), see the scan [here](https://wpdirectory.net/search/01CYP0BAZN1SHBDJ9T8M63TC4R). There are also 424 plugins that do the same for the content e.g. JetPack. See scan [here](https://wpdirectory.net/search/01CYP0ZJVTF3PJJTZG2W36B6CY). So this is widely used approach in plugins and core.

Comment: Thanks for all the info